# JQUERY Click event doesn't work only at the first click call

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, onclick, web-frontend

In the code, I try to print the name that is saved as a data value for each button.. but on the first click event call it doesn't work. while after the first time it works normally.

NOTE: off('click') function it is because without it this function fires multiple times with the following rate: 1times on a click, 2times on the next click, 3times on the next click, 4times on the next click, ...... and so on.

So it(off('click')) prevents this to happen.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-add', () => {

   $(".btn-add").off('click').on('click', (obj) => {

      const nameOfProduct = obj.currentTarget.value;

      console.log("name selected = " + nameOfProduct);

   })

})
```

Comment: Change `$(document).on('click', '.btn-add', () => {` to `$(document).ready(() => {`

Comment: If you read down your code line by line, it says: 1) first click on the page for btn-add -> add a *new* click handler (and stop).  2) 2nd click -> same doc.on click, add a *new* click handler, but also fire the click handler added in step 1.  3) 3rd click: same doc.on click, add another *new* click handler, but also fire click handler added in step 1 *and* click handler added in step 2.

Comment: I got your idea but unfortunately, it doesn't fire at all.

Comment: You may need the event delegation, so instead of replacing the first line, keep that line and remove the inner line - remove *just* the line `$(".btn-add").off('click').on('click', (obj) => {` (and `})`) keeping the doc.on(click, btn-add and the handler.

Comment: Wow!.. It worked .. thanks a lot...

Comment: See this answer for more info:  [event binding on dynamically added elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want to do, after document is ready, add button click handler:

```
 $(document).ready(() => {
    $(".btn-add").on('click', (obj) => {

      const nameOfProduct = obj.currentTarget.value;

      console.log("name selected = " + nameOfProduct);

   })
 })
```

Your code removes handler then adds handler to the button click after every click on button..
So after first click, you try to remove, then you add handler.
After that you fire handler function, remove handler and add handler, which is probably not what you want to do.